# <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender> not working

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

`AjaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender` not working on `UpdatePanel` why?

when I run `ValidatorCalloutExtender` without update panel it works fine;
but when apply `updatepanel` it's not working.

`validator` calls out code inside the update panel but it is still not working.

Anybody could tell me why?

**Code:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>

            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundle" />

        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
            <table>

                 <tr> <td>Full Name :</td>
                     <td style="width: 235px">
                     &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="220px" Height="40px"></asp:TextBox>
                     <br />

                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="NReq"
                           ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
                            Display="None"
                             SetFocusOnError="true"
                            ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Full Name Is Required." />
                         <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="NReqE"
                            TargetControlID="NReq"
                             HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" />
                     </td>

                 </tr>

                 <tr> <td>Father Name :</td>
                     <td style="width: 235px">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="220px" Height="40px"></asp:TextBox>

                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
                           ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
                            Display="None" DisplayOnClick="true"
                             SetFocusOnError="true"
                            ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Father Name Is Required." />
                         <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1"
                            TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
                             HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" />
                 </td>
                 </tr>
             <tr> <td>
                     &nbsp;</td> <td style="width: 235px">
                         <br />
                         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Missing Person Detail" Height="40px" Width="220px" OnClick="Button1_Click" CssClass="btn-warning" />
                     </td></tr>

            </table>
 </ContentTemplate>

        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1"/>
        </Triggers>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser's console?

Comment: No Error Ever Thing run Perfectaly,

Comment: ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender working without update panel,

Comment: but when i apply ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender inside the update panel its not working why?

Comment: It seems that toolkit can not find a control that ValidatorCallout is bound to because controls inside the UpdatePanel have to be found a little different way. It's just a theory, need to check it.